# dynamic conditions for mysql select

Tags: php, mysql

I have inputs in a form that sends an ajax request (with `serializeArray()`) and based on those checked inputs the query gets different data (like filters). But I have problems handling these dynamic conditions, if it's just 1 (`AND`) it's working, but for some reason more than 1 it throws an error (that apparently everything is fine):

```
MySQLi failed: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't2.type = 2
 OR t2.type = 3

                                   LIMIT ?,' at line 5<br><br />
```

The problem must be either on how the variables are created or how are printed inside the `prepare()` statement:

```
$filter_type = isset( $_POST['type'] ) ?  filter_input( INPUT_POST , 'type', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT , FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY ) : NULL;

if ($filter_type != NULL) {
    foreach ($filter_type as $type=>$value) {
        if ($type === 0) {
            $type_cond = "\nAND t2.type = " . $value; // (int) instead of filter_input()?
        } else {
            $type_cond .= $type_cond . "\nOR t2.type = " . $value;
        }
    }
}

// I manually set $table, based on post (but not directly)
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare(' SELECT t1.id, t2.*
                               FROM ' . $table . ' t1
                               INNER JOIN property t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
                               WHERE t2.use = ?
                               ' . $type_cond
                                 . $filter_status
                                 . $filter_bhk
                                 . $filter_city
                                 . $filter_zone . '
                               LIMIT ?, ?')) {
```

Where's the problem?

EDIT: The <s>expected</s> actual query, after checking 2 checkboxes would be `$filter_type = array(2, 3)` so:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.*
FROM for_sale t1
INNER JOIN property t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
WHERE t2.use = 1AND t2.type = 2
OR t2.type = 3
-- $filter_status = NULL; but not printing
-- $filter_bhk = NULL; but not printing
-- $filter_city = NULL; but not printing
-- $filter_zone = NULL; but not printing
LIMIT ?, ?
```

FIX by @MarcB (in comments).

```
$filter_type = "\nAND t2.ty...";
```

Comment: since is a syntax error, can you post the query resulting from code?

Comment: show the actual query statement you generated, AFTER all the variables are inserted. The actual error is **BEFORE** the spot indicated in the error message.

Comment: Yes, they are just 2, `AND t2.type = 2\n OR t2.type = 3`. That would be the generated query.

Comment: Well if you look at the generate SQL, your problem becomes clear - some of your variables don't have values in them.

Comment: But they need to be in the query. So the NULLs are the problem? But the variables needs to be there, or how can I add them if someone checks one checkbox to filter? Maybe unsetting the variable if it's null??

Comment: The NULLs weren't the problem, I just put them because I thought they were printing but no. So no need to `unset()` nothing.

Comment: @MarcB Thanks, it took my time but I finally got it... `use = 1AND t2.ty...`